# Angular Project downloaded from github started at my windows PC not working on my mac ( Blank Page)

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, angular, single-page-application

I have problem with my angular/dotnet project.
I've started it on my Windows PC using Visual Studio Code, and now since I want to go somewhere i need to download it to my laptop. I've used clone option from github, downloaded js, Net. Net part starts normally, but Angular project starts using ng serve but all what it shows is the blank page.When I start a new angular app it is showed correctly.

Not really know what to check, the only problem showing in console is

Your global Angular CLI version (9.1.3) is greater than your local
version (9.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Normally, huge dependencies like node_modules won't upload to the Github. You can simply download all the required dependencies by npm package manager. just type npm install in the
cmd.

Comment: So the package must contain some dependencies coming from Windows because it shows me the pacakge is to big to upload

Comment: what do u mean by "windows" ? is it saying that "if you commit this, you can't commit anymore" or something like that? @JJPartyBoy

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found the solution
I've deleted node_modules file and used nom -install